# How to export specific number of rows?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, winforms, closedxml

I want to export specific number of rows. For example, I want to just export 500 rows or 100 rows. I am stuck with this code.

```
private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the '_GPS_TrackerDataSet.ParsedReadings' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    this.parsedReadingsTableAdapter.Fill(this._GPS_TrackerDataSet.ParsedReadings);

}

private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SaveFileDialog SFD = new SaveFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel Workbook |*.xlsx" })
    {
        if (SFD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
            XLWorkbook XLW = new XLWorkbook();
            XLW.Worksheets.Add(this._GPS_TrackerDataSet.ParsedReadings.CopyToDataTable(), "ParsedReadings");

            XLW.SaveAs(SFD.FileName);
                        
            MessageBox.Show("Success.", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure, you want to export a number of rows from parsedReadingsTableAdapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some LINQ to extract nth number of rows from the DataSet.

```
DataTable table = _GPS_TrackerDataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().ToList().Take(100).CopyToDataTable();
```

This assumes the you are using the first table in the dataset, and you want the first 100.